# Using GKGameCenterControllerDelegate with SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I am trying to add a GKGameCenterController Delegate to my class in Swift, but I get the error:

```
Type 'GameScene' does not conform to protocol 'GKGameCenterControllerDelegate'
```

This is the order I have the delegates in:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {
```

Just simply trying to add GameCenter capabilities to my app.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the error

> does not conform to protocol

It is usually because of not overriding the methods of the protocol.
In your class override the method provided by the [GKGameCenterControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate_Ref/) protocol

```
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {

 }
```

It will work fine afterwards.